# Does $Ax=b$ have a solution for every vector $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: matrices

Let $A$= $\begin{bmatrix}3 & 1 & -1\\0 & 4 &0\\6 &3&-2\end{bmatrix}$ and $x= \begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}$ and $b=\begin{bmatrix}0\\4\\1 \end{bmatrix}$

Does $Ax = b$ have a solution for every vector $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$

So I went about this first by doing the matrix multiplication and got

$A$= $\begin{bmatrix}3x_1+x_2-x_3\\4x_2\\6x_1+3x_2-2x_3\end{bmatrix}$= $\begin{bmatrix}0\\4\\1\\\end{bmatrix}$

Now how do I go about solving this matrix?

Comment: If the rank of $A$ is less than 3, then there would be vectors $b$ in $\mathbb R^3$ such that $[A|b]$ has rank greater than that of $A$ and therefore there would be no solution. So you have to check whether $A$ has a full rank, i.e whether $rank A=3$. This is the same as saying that the image of the operator $A$ is the whole $\mathbb R^3$.

Answer (score 0):

$\det A=0\Rightarrow rank A<3$. This means that the image of $A$ is a strict subspace of $\mathbb R^3$, so there are vectors $b\in\mathbb R^3$ for which there is no $x\in\mathbb R^3$ such that $Ax=b$.

Answer (score 0):

The equation $Ax=b$ has solutions if and only $$\operatorname{rank}A=\operatorname{rank}[Ab]\qquad([Ab]\enspace\text{denotes the augmented matrix}).$$
In this case, the solutions are an affine space, and the *codimension* of this affine space is equal to $\operatorname{rank}A$.

In the present case, you can check by row reduction that  $\operatorname{rank}A=2$, while $\operatorname{rank}[Ab]=3$. Hence there's no solution.

Comment: I have not learned this concept of rank yet... could I solve this through normal row reduction and then backwards substitution?

Comment: The rank is simply the number of non-zero lines in the row-reduced matrix. Even if your teacher didn't use the word, he used the concept behind the word. The condition means that each time a line of $A$ is $0$,the corresponding line of the (row-reduced) augmented matrix must also be $0$, which gives  you consistency conditions.